# Passenger + Bundler - Gems Not Loaded from Deployed App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, passenger

I am trying to get a ruby app running via Phusion_Passenger (6.0.15) and Apache (2.4.54). The app is OpenProject (v12) and the system is a Raspberry PI4, but I guess this does not matter for the problem at hand.

When loading the app via Passenger I have the problem that gems are incorrectly loaded from the "system" gem list and not the openproject app vendor/bundle folder

- gems installed as given in Gemfile.lock via `bundle install --deployment`
- manually confirmed that the gems are indeed all correctly available in `./vendor/bundle` folder
- Passenger loads and reports an error loading the app
- Looking into the errors it shows that it is incorrect versions and / or missing gems due to the fact that apparently only gems from the system wide locations (more specifically: from the user space gems that are also around) are pulled, not from `vendor/bundle`
- Passenger bundler/setup seems to be working somehow but something is wrong with the load paths apparently
- looking at "activated_gems" from the log files (Passenger friendly error pages) it shows that it is all the wrong versions, i.e. not from vendor/bundle; if I remove a gem from the default, it then also disappears from the "activated_gems"
- user and users rights seem to be correct; passenger reports the user ("openproject") under which the app should be running, vendor/bundle directories and sub-folders are owned by this user and accessible

Below are some more details from the error pages / log provided by passenger

Are there any ideas what could be wrong and causing passenger bundler to not pick up the gems from the `vendor/bundle` folder?

**ruby_info**

```
RUBY_VERSION = 3.1.2
RUBY_PLATFORM = aarch64-linux
RUBY_ENGINE = ruby
RubyGems version = 3.3.25
RubyGems paths = ["/home/openproject/openproject/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0"]
```

**Environment Variables**

```
USER = openproject
TEXTDOMAIN = Linux-PAM
SHLVL = 0
HOME = /home/openproject
WSGI_ENV = development
PYTHONUNBUFFERED = 1
PASSENGER_USE_FEEDBACK_FD = true
APACHE_RUN_DIR = /var/run/apache2
APACHE_PID_FILE = /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
LOGNAME = openproject
JOURNAL_STREAM = 8:19903
SERVER_SOFTWARE = Apache/2.4.54 (Debian) Phusion_Passenger/6.0.15
RACK_ENV = development
RBENV_SHELL = bash
PATH = /home/openproject/openproject/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/bin:/home/openproject/.nodenv/shims:/home/openproject/.nodenv/bin:/home/openproject/.rbenv/shims:/home/openproject/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
INVOCATION_ID = fcc115b63f334260aa3d8095470cde64
APACHE_LOCK_DIR = /var/lock/apache2
LANG = C
PASSENGER_SPAWN_WORK_DIR = /tmp/passenger.spawn.XXXXA4E1WH
SHELL = /bin/bash
IN_PASSENGER = 1
NODE_PATH = /home/openproject/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/passenger-6.0.15/src/nodejs_supportlib
APACHE_RUN_GROUP = www-data
APACHE_RUN_USER = www-data
APACHE_LOG_DIR = /var/log/apache2
RAILS_ENV = development
SECRET_KEY_BASE = 1f1b879d25c6e48581ea65067c808ac965bd7598eb0bdf2ba497865e32113cbf5e5a290b59bfab62e882c03eac3ff61efb4cbc954984c422c5770ee931d0c4d0
NODENV_SHELL = bash
PWD = /home/openproject/openproject
PASSENGER_APP_ENV = development
NODE_ENV = development
BUNDLER_ORIG_BUNDLE_BIN_PATH = BUNDLER_ENVIRONMENT_PRESERVER_INTENTIONALLY_NIL
BUNDLER_ORIG_BUNDLE_GEMFILE = BUNDLER_ENVIRONMENT_PRESERVER_INTENTIONALLY_NIL
BUNDLER_ORIG_BUNDLER_VERSION = BUNDLER_ENVIRONMENT_PRESERVER_INTENTIONALLY_NIL
BUNDLER_ORIG_GEM_HOME = BUNDLER_ENVIRONMENT_PRESERVER_INTENTIONALLY_NIL
BUNDLER_ORIG_GEM_PATH = BUNDLER_ENVIRONMENT_PRESERVER_INTENTIONALLY_NIL
BUNDLER_ORIG_MANPATH = BUNDLER_ENVIRONMENT_PRESERVER_INTENTIONALLY_NIL
BUNDLER_ORIG_PATH = /home/openproject/.nodenv/shims:/home/openproject/.nodenv/bin:/home/openproject/.rbenv/shims:/home/openproject/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
BUNDLER_ORIG_RB_USER_INSTALL = BUNDLER_ENVIRONMENT_PRESERVER_INTENTIONALLY_NIL
BUNDLER_ORIG_RUBYLIB = BUNDLER_ENVIRONMENT_PRESERVER_INTENTIONALLY_NIL
BUNDLER_ORIG_RUBYOPT = BUNDLER_ENVIRONMENT_PRESERVER_INTENTIONALLY_NIL
GEM_PATH = 
GEM_HOME = /home/openproject/openproject/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0
BUNDLE_BIN_PATH = /home/openproject/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.12/exe/bundle
BUNDLE_GEMFILE = /home/openproject/openproject/Gemfile
BUNDLER_VERSION = 2.3.12
RUBYOPT = -r/home/openproject/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.12/lib/bundler/setup
RUBYLIB = /home/openproject/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.12/lib
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in the end I figured it out. Probably more of a workaround. Also according to the documentation I have read it should not have been necessary, but anyways.

Adding

```
SetEnv GEM_PATH /home/openproject/openproject/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0
```

to /etc/apache2/sites-available/openproject.conf